# HSQLDB Login Authentication Problem

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

Hi I am using spring for datasource configuration of hsqldb database. my spring bean is:

```
<bean id="adapterDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/db/hsqldb.jar" />
        <property name="username" value="lmexadapterdba" />
        <property name="password" value="lmexadapterdba123#" />
</bean>
```

the every thing is fine in datasource, but when i run my project on server it's give me a error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: User not found: LMEXADAPTERDBA
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1266)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1240)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:882)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:471)
    at com.platysgroup.lmex.controller.LoginController.processLogin(LoginController.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

But i have a user with the name lmexadapterdba but in small case not in uppercase. bca hsqldb converts it into uppercase it's not working. please help me to how can i solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In HSQLDB 2.x user name and passwords are case sensitive. You should use double quotes for user name and single quotes for password definition:

```
CREATE USER "lmexadapterdba" PASSWORD 'lmexadapterdba123#'
```

If you do not use double-quotes, the user name is converted to all uppercase at the time of creation.

In HSQLDB 1.8 and earlier, user name is not case-sensitive. It is converted into all-uppercase at the time of creation.

Comment: from where we have to create user my meaning is like from HSQL Database manager

Comment: Your URL is incorrect, it should specify the name of a file, not the name of the hsqldb.jar. Use the DatabaseManager to connect to the database and create the user.